# C++ matrix template class slice

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, matrix, slice

In order to learn about C++ templates I am writing a simple Matrix class.  So far it has been working well, but I want to add the ability to slice the Matrix to extract a sub-matrix.  I am struggling to figure out how to define the size of the return matrix.  I have tried the following:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

template<typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
class Matrix
{
    public:
        Matrix(void): m_data{0} {}

        Matrix(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> m)
        {
            for(auto i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); i++)
            {
                for(auto j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); j++)
                {
                    (*this)(i - m.begin(), j - i->begin()) = *j;
                }
            }
        }

        T& operator()(const std::size_t i, const std::size_t j)
        {
            return m_data.at(i + j * N);
        }

        const T& operator()(const std::size_t i, const std::size_t j) const
        {
            return m_data.at(i + j * N);
        }

        template<std::size_t X, std::size_t Y>
        Matrix<T,X,Y> slice(const std::size_t iStart, const std::size_t iEnd, const std::size_t jStart, const std::size_t jEnd)
        {
            Matrix<T,iEnd-iStart+1,jEnd-jStart+1> result;

            for(std::size_t i = iStart; i <= iEnd; i++)
            {
                for(std::size_t j = jStart; j <= jEnd; j++)
                {
                    result(i - iStart, j - jStart) = (*this)(i,j);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    Matrix<double,3,3> m1 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    Matrix<double,2,2> m2 = m1.slice(0,1,0,1);
    return 0;
}
```

But I just get an error saying that `'iEnd' is not a constant expression`.  What would be the correct way to go about this?

Comment: Function parameters cannot be used as template parameters.

Comment: To expand on the comment by @NeilKirk, non-type template arguments must be *compile-time* constants. A function argument, even if declared `const`, can never be a compile-time constant.

Comment: In terms of your design, you want to have the size of the slice known at run-time but return a matrix of exactly the correct size, but the matrix size must be determined at compile-time. That's not going to work. Either make the slice size compile-time through template parameters, or dynamically allocate the matrix size and make the sizes non-template parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use function parameters to instantiate templates. You need to pass in the sizes as template arguments to `slice`:

```
template<std::size_t iStart, std::size_t iEnd, std::size_t jStart, std::size_t jEnd,
         std::size_t I = iEnd-iStart+1, std::size_t J = jEnd-jStart+1>
Matrix<T,I,J> slice()
{
    Matrix<T,I,J> result;
    ///...
    return result;
}
```